# Problems updating jtable java

Tags: java, swing, jtable

i made a class where i create my jtable. I have some issues because when i try to update it, it does not work (nothing happens - i think the way i am trying to update it is wrong?). What am i doing wrong?

```
class tableClass
{
    public Vector rowData = null; 
    public Vector columnNames = null; 
    private JTable jTable; 
    DefaultTableModel model;

    public tableClass(JPanel jPanel, Vector rowDataInput, Vector columnNamesInput)
    {       
        rowData = rowDataInput; 
        columnNames = columnNamesInput;

        jTable = new JTable(rowData, columnNames);
        jTable.setFillsViewportHeight(true);

        JScrollPane jScrollPane = new JScrollPane(jTable);
        jScrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 100));
        jPanel.add(jScrollPane,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    public void updateTable(Vector rowDataInput)
    {
        rowData = rowDataInput;  
        model =(DefaultTableModel)jTable.getModel();  
        model.fireTableDataChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: you are not changing anything in `updateTable`, what do you expect will happen if you change nothing?

Comment: 'rowData' contains the new content data and i believe that model.fireTableDataChanged(); is supposed to refresh it?

Comment: you are pointing `rowData` to `rowDataInput`, `JTable` does not know about this, it still points to the old `rowData`. I believe you get confused with pointers here. Bottom line, tell your table model that the data changed and then call `fireTableDataChanged` which by the way only notifies attached views, such as `JTable`

Comment: @stryba - no, _never_ call fireTableDataChanged from code outside the model, that's _exclusively_ the job of the model implementation.

Comment: @kleopatra you are right I forgot we are outside the model, my bad. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rowData` is given to the JTable in the constructor.  Then in `updateTable` you simply update the `rowData` field in your `TableClass`.  Therefore neither the `JTable` nor its `TableModel` knows anything about your changes.  You need to update the table's model in `updateTable`.

In other words, when you update `rowData` in `updateTable` you are not updating the same `rowData` object you passed into the JTable in your constructor.

The below class is functionally the same as your class.  Does this make it clearer why what you're doing has no effect?  You see, rowData is in no way shared by TableClass and the JTable.  And it shouldn't be - you should be updating the TableModel.  You can implement your own TableModel and update that object with your changes.

```
class tableClass
{
    public Vector columnNames = null; 
    private JTable jTable; 
    DefaultTableModel model;

    public tableClass(JPanel jPanel, Vector rowDataInput, Vector columnNamesInput)
    {       
        Vector rowData = rowDataInput; 
        columnNames = columnNamesInput;

        jTable = new JTable(rowData, columnNames);
        jTable.setFillsViewportHeight(true);

        JScrollPane jScrollPane = new JScrollPane(jTable);
        jScrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 100));
        jPanel.add(jScrollPane,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    public void updateTable(Vector rowDataInput)
    {
        Vector rowData = rowDataInput;  
        model =(DefaultTableModel)jTable.getModel();  
        model.fireTableDataChanged();
    }
}
```

You could change your code as follows to prove that the changes work.  **Note** that i'm **not** advocating this approach - you should really implement your own TableModel, but simply showing you how to change the underlying model itself and therefore see the changes take place in the JTable on-screen.

**EDIT** As this answer was accepted, and following comments from @kleopatra and using @Adam's answer (+1) i've update the below code to show how to update the entire data Vector or Vectors in `updateTable`.  I still would not do it like this in production code, but at least this is functionally correct and closer to the OPs question.

```
class MyTable {
    private Vector columnNames = null; 
    private JTable jTable;

    public tableClass(JPanel jPanel, Vector rowDataInput, Vector columnNamesInput) {
        // ...
        jTable = new JTable(rowData, columnNames);
        // ...
    }

    public void updateTable(Vector rowDataInput) {
        model =(DefaultTableModel)jTable.getModel();

        // Now actually update the model with your new data:
        model.setDataVector(rowDataInput, columnNames);
    }
}
```

As i said, this isn't a good way to do it, but i'm just trying to show you why what you're doing is not working. :)

Comment: in update i also have 'model =(DefaultTableModel)jTable.getModel();  
model.fireTableDataChanged();' or am i missing something?

Comment: Yes - the rowData you passed to the JTable in your constructor never changes...  You simply are updating the reference to rowData and not rowData itself or anything the JTable knows about.

Comment: Is there any chance you could show me an example please? would much appreciate it, on the update part

Comment: unfortunately your code doesn't do anything the OP (probably) wants to achieve: which is something like bulk-replace the dataVector that backs the DefaultTableModel

Comment: It still doesn't sound like you've changed the model.  Please update (add your new code) your question and i'll take another look :).

Comment: @kleopatra agreed.  I'm going for guidance rather than pasting in working code (which would be wildly different from the OPs question).

Comment: there is _no_ excuse for repeating errors - he'll think it's okay and repeat them ad infinitum

Comment: @kleopatra actually i don't think this question is about JTable at all - i think it's a basic misunderstanding or Java object references which is what i'm trying to explain to the OP.  Adam's answer is better than mine (+1) in showing the better way.  However i feel you learn nothing if you just get shown the working code (with simple questions like this).

Comment: @kleopatra i've now updated my answer to show a working (but IMHO still incorrect) solution.

Answer (score 2):

To point you in the right direction here is a slightly cleaner working version of your class. If you've got a lot of data please be aware updating tables like this is not efficient! You'd be better subclassing AbstractTableModel yourself and mapping to whatever data structures you have already.

```
public class Table {
    public Vector<String> columnNames;
    private JTable table;

    public Table(JPanel panel, Vector<Vector<Object>> rowData,
            Vector<String> columnNames) {
        this.columnNames = columnNames;

        table = new JTable(rowData, columnNames);
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 100));
        panel.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    public void updateTable(Vector<Vector<Object>> rowData) {
        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
        model.setDataVector(rowData, columnNames);
    }
```

Comment: no need to fire anything from the outside, DefaultTableModel is well-behaved :-)

Comment: @kleopatra Good point. Now edited, there's almost nothing left!

Comment: @Adam i updated my answer to include your (better and more complete) example showing how to replace all the underlying data in one go.  I upvoted your answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

When you write:

```
rowData = rowDataInput;
```

it does not change the `rowData` you passed to the jTable in the constructor.